# Add Grand Total Row of Every Column BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sum

I have this table

```
    Row     Type      ValueA        ValueB       ValueC
---------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------
    1    |    A    |   1000    |    50       |     10
    2    |    B    |   2000    |    40       |     20
```

My desired results are

```
      Row     Type      ValueA        ValueB       ValueC
    ---------+---------+-----------+-------------+-------------
        1    |    A    |   1000    |    50       |     10
        2    |    B    |   2000    |    40       |     20 
 Grand Total |         |   3000    |    90       |     30
```

Is there any way to do it? Tried using case function but it adds more column not row. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There are ways of doing this using complex SQL queries, however, practically speaking it would not be useful. 
It is always a good idea to have a separation of concerns to make your code and queries as reusable as possible. In this case: one query to show table data, another query to show the aggregate table data (Totals).

Comment: Check Rollup https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax

Answer (score 3):

try below simple approach

```
select * from your_table union all
select 'Grand Total', null, sum(ValueA), sum(ValueB), sum(ValueC)
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data as in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select '1' `Row`, 'A' Type, 1000 ValueA, 50 ValueB, 10 ValueC union all
  select '2', 'B', 2000, 40, 20 
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: This just worked perfectly on my example. Thank you, Mikhail